# ISTQB question: Statement Coverage and Decision Coverage with loop

Tags: test-strategy, coverage, istqb, certification, whitebox-testing

I'm learning `ISTQB` and encountering a question about `Statement and Decision coverage` in a sample exam of `ISTQB` org.

Evaluate    the following   `control    flow    diagram`    and determine   the `statement coverage`    and `decision    coverage`  resulting   from    the execution   of  the following   test    cases:
[image]

- A-B-D-E-F
- A-B-C

There are 4 answer choice:

a. 33%  statement,  100% decision

b. 50%  statement,  50% decision

c. 100% statement,  75% decision

d. 100% statement,  100% decision

As the answer sheet, the `correct one is: C`. I understand why 100% statement , but 75% decision. We have 4 Test Cases:

1. A-B-C (test case 1)
2. A-B-D-E-F (test case 2)
3. A-B-D-A-B-C (test case 3)
4. A-B-D-A-B-D-E-F (test case 4)

So the `coverage percentage` is = the `number of run test cases` / the `total of test cases` = 2/4 = 50%. But it is not the same as the answer - 75%.

Am I understanding incorrectly?

Could you please help me point out what wrong it is and share more ideas on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 4 possible decisions/branches:

1. B-C
2. B-D
3. D-E
4. D-A

The 2 test cases A-B-D-E-F and A-B-C only cover 3 (1. – 3.) out of 4, which is why it's 75% decision/branch coverage.